# wxWidgets: obtaining application path

Tags: wxwidgets, filepath

How one can obtain path to module?

I am writing extension enclosed in a DLL and want to get path to my library in runtime.

**Update**

Of course first way worked fine

```
static wxString GetModulePath()
{
    static wxString path;

    WCHAR buf[512] = {0};
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, 511);
    path = buf;

    return wxPathOnly(path);
}
```

but finally I ended with second one

```
wxStandardPaths sp;
wxLogError(sp.GetPluginsDir());
```

Comment: i am just looking for 'proper', 'crossplatform' way

Comment: Now that you have accepted the first answer I'm a little confused about what you really want to achieve: get the location of the extension from inside the host application? Get the location of the extension module from itself, once it is loaded? And if cross-platform, why accept the answer with the Windows API function?

Comment: get the location of the extension module from itself, once it is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Note that you don't need your own instance of the wxStandardPaths class, you can simply write "wxStandardPaths::Get().GetPluginsDir()" to use the unique global object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`wxStandardPaths`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstandardpaths.html#wxstandardpaths) class.  For your problem its [`GetExecutablePath()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstandardpaths.html#wxstandardpathsgetexecutablepath) or [`GetPluginsDir()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstandardpaths.html#wxstandardpathsgetpluginsdir) methods could be used - I'm just not sure what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I used

```
    #include "wx/stdpaths.h"
    #include "dialogsApp.h"
    #include "dialogsMain.h"

    IMPLEMENT_APP(dialogsApp);

    bool dialogsApp::OnInit()
    {

        wxString xpath;
        xpath = wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath();
```

That seems to work.

Comment: @ile: This is not redundant. Phil shows how exactly to call it. My +1. A minor enhancement would only be to join the two last lines to `wxString xpath(wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath());`.

Comment: @ile: OK. This was *your* thought which does not mean that everyone thinks that way. If one does not know wx, it may not be that easy to find how to call it. And sorry, I was upset a little by your behaviour (my fault). Who are you to give beginners the orders like *remove it*?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't wxWidgets specific.  Windows has a function called [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx) that does what you want.  The link is to the msdn page.

Comment: And just how cross-platform is that?

Comment: Not at all.  GetModuleFileName is a Win32 specific api.